# Data Table component in a Screen Flow does not display all fields from a Variable

Tags: lightning-datatable, datatable, screen-flow

I'm using 2 Assignment elements to populate a Quote Line Item variable. There are a number of decision required for Sales Price, hence the 2nd Assignment element.

In the debug the fields in the variable are allocated with the correct values, however in the Data Table, only the fields from populated via the 1st Assignment element are displayed.

In the debug also looks like the Data Table component is not retrieving the fields from the 2nd Assignment element at all

Note: The same logic I am using somewhere else in the Flow and it works as expected. Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to read [How to Ask](/help/how-to-ask) and take the [tour](/tour). Including a [Minimal, Complete and Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be helpful